# Holomorphic functional calculus

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I am learning a new topic about holomorphic functional calculus, however I cannot understand
this definition.

Definition: Let $T$ a bounded operator in a Hilbert Space, and $f$ a holomorphic fonction in a open set U, we set
\begin{equation}
f(T)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\partial U}(z-T)^{-1}f(z)dz
\end{equation}
What I don't understand, it's in deed the definition of the integral,
How I can integrate $(z-T)^{-1}$?, or I am only evaluating $f(z)$ in the resolven of $T$?
or it is a multiplication?

Maybe my question is very basic, but I don't find any book that explains in a better way.

Comment: $z \longmapsto (z-T)^{-1}$ is a continuous function $\partial U \rightarrow \mathcal{L}_c(H)$, so you can consider a contour integral.

Comment: So, the integral could be written like $ f(T)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\partial U}(z-T)^{-1}(z)f(z)dz$

Comment: Well, $(z-T)^{-1}(z)$ is $(z-T)^{-1}$... If you want everything to be perfectly defined, the equation should be $2i\pi f(T): u \in H \longmapsto \int_{\partial U}{f(z)(z-T)^{-1}(u)\,dz}$.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, that's what I was l looking.

Comment: I think the question is essentially "since $(zI-T)^{-1}$ is an operator for all $z$ in the resolvent of $T$, how do I integrate an operator-valued function?" There is a thorough if somewhat terse explanation in Appendix 2 (pp. 245-251) of this set of notes: https://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/media/analysis/lehrmaterial_anapde/hallerd/ISem21complete.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is better to write

$$\begin{equation}
f(T)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\partial U}f(z)(z-T)^{-1}dz
\end{equation}$$

instead of

$$\begin{equation}
f(T)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\partial U}(z-T)^{-1}f(z)dz
\end{equation}.$$

Let $g(z):=f(z)(z-T)^{-1}.$ Then $g$ is continuous on $ \partial U$. Observe that we have $\partial U \subset \rho(T)$.

Hence

$$f(T)= \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\partial U}g(z)dz.$$